# Azure - Github deploy to Storage Account on virtual network

Tags: azure, github, azure-storage, devops, github-actions

I have a Storage Account on a virtual network that delivers an externally-facing static website through Application Gateway.

I want to be able to deploy changes to that website through a Github Action.  I though this would be straightforward.

However, the Action YML script that I wrote to upload to the Storage Account doesn't work, because the upload attempt is being blocked by network rules.

I see that I can whitelist external connection IPs on the Storage Account, but there are too many possible IPs from Github to whitelist.

Is there a reasonable way to deploy from a Github Action to an internally-connected Storage Account?  Or is it necessary to take a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, currently, I believe the best solution is to whitelist the external connection IP address from your Github as it takes a few cost and more straightforward without deploying any other resources in the Azure.

There are [Trusted Microsoft services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security#trusted-microsoft-services) in the Exception in the Azure Storage firewalls and virtual networks. It could pass the resources when you set the network rules in the Azure storage firewalls. However, it's useless for your external Github Action.